# CSS - Transition on top & box shadow not working?

Tags: css, animation, button, transition

I'm trying to add a smooth transition on the button on hover and click but it doesn't work. Tried `transition: all .5s ease-in-out;` , `transition: top .5s ease-in-out;` but no bueno. I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

```css
.intro a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 20px 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=0px, offy=1px);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffe5c4, 0 10px 0 #cf920f;
}

.intro a:hover {
    top: 10px;

    background-color: #F78900;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffe5c4, inset 0 -3px 0 #cf920f;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <a href="#">Transition button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `top: 0` in `.intro a` initially